# Kickstarter bike too good to be true?

Tags: road-bike

the pro version looks to be great with decent components but am I just getting wooed by the video? How do I tell if it would be worth the 2K?

https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/speedx/speedx-leopard-the-first-ever-smart-aero-road-bike

Comment: I'm not sure what about that looks too good to be true, just a carbon bike with some niche features. Are you just trying to drive traffic to your own kickstarter? Also, the kickstarter page says they are based in San Jose CA, but the speedx website gives a Beijing address. If anyone thinks this is an innovative startup in Silicone Valley, they've been misled. This is most likely being produced in a big Chinese production facility (not that that is necessarily a bad thing, but just misleading). Also, your link is broken.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't spend that kind of money without riding the bike first to see how it fit me. Also, all that integrated hidden cabling sounds good from an aerodynamic point of view, but seems like it would be a bugged to maintain. Also, I really don't see the pout of an integrated bike computer, especially with so much changing with those in recent years. Also I would question how one would resolve any warranty issues with a bike bought from a company that doesn't really have much of a history.

Comment: Bikes don't need to be smart, that's one of the rider's jobs.

Comment: I've replaced the link with one that works.

Comment: @Criggie when spammers get their link wrong that's a good thing. Fixing it... not so much.

Comment: @Mσᶎ Good point.  I suspect OP is legitimately shopping for a new bike, and internet research is informative.  I see that bike as being a mid range carbon bike with some mid range groupset for a mid range price.  Its got some custom unique and proprietary bike computer/mount on the front, which look irreplaceable.    Some things should not be bought sight-unseen, including boots, eye glasses, clothes, gloves, wives, and bicycles.  Gotta try before you buy.

Comment: @Criggie I suspect you're wrong.  See OP's prior question along with having a history of plagiarizing answers...

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to judge the product as a bicycle - no test ride, no company reputation, no customer reports  on the internet.  What does differentiate it is a not particularly astounding cycling computer which happens to be built in.  There they seem to bucking the trend:  bicycle makers specializing in bicycles, electronic device and software makers specializing in their crafts.  As if it is already not hard enough to make something distinctive and competitive in either sphere.